# Identifying activities in Activity diagrams

Tags: architecture, uml, diagrams

I need to create an activity diagram for  particular SMS sending task from a computer. Following is the SMS process

1. prepare message
2. search for the dongle
3. if dongle found then connect to it else display an error message and stop
4. send message
5. display success or fail message and stop

But the problem here is, this SMS sending activity **ONLY** get called when an intruder alarm is raised. So, should I add this to the diagram as well? If I add it, the process will looks like below

1. Alarm raised
2. prepare message
3. search for the dongle
4. if dongle found then connect to it else display an error message and stop
5. send message
6. display success or fail message and stop

Which way should I follow? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could use an accept-event action to wait for an intruder alarm, then use a call-behavior action to call the SMS-sending activity.